# How to run two different models in single frame?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, data-science-model, parallel

I have mask_detector.model and yolov3 social distancing weights.

I want to run them simultaneously with a single webcam stream.

how can I run them both i.e. detecting mask and social distancing model together?

Answer (score 0):

Use ray or Numba for Parallel Computation. Question is "are not you able to do transfer learning to detect both in one single model"?